# Powershell script not running through Informatica Powercenter

Tags: powershell, informatica-powercenter

I have a Powershell script which runs perfectly directly on my local machine using Powershell and command line. But when running in post-session command in Informatica, it is not getting executed, only the session gets succeeded.            I am calling bat script using this command- `$PMRootDir\Scripts\GetColumns.bat` . And this bat script is further invoking Powershell script. Need help on this.

Comment: So you've got a Powershell that calls a bat that calls a Powershell? If you cannot simplify the chain, add a bunch of debug statements and log what's going on into a log file.

Comment: Check the session log if the post session command produces an error

Comment: I presume the script is available for the Integration Service. Add few debug statements just to check if it's properly getting called.